# On the one hand ... on the other 

Tags: phrases

*Drawing an equivalence between X and Y* is a standard English expression which runs into problems when X and/or Y is itself a comma-delimited list.

> Slave_jed, "slavery", in BDSM terms,
>   really should be written in inverted
>   commas. It's a completely different
>   thing to real slavery. Drawing an
>   equivalence between torture, false
>   imprisonment, and rape on the one hand
>   and a sexual kink on the other is
>   highly insulting.

In the quote above, I framed X and Y with *on the one hand* and *on the other*. Is this the best way to fix this or is there a more elegant phrasing I could have used?

Comment: To clarify, for the purpose of getting asides out of the way: Slave_jed started talking about BDSM slavery in a forum discussion on real sexual slavery. I think in a situation where the BDSM context is already established, it's okay to talk about BDSM slavery without inverted commas. Probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to be more clear, you could rephrase with:

> Drawing an equivalence between *the* torture, false imprisonment, and rape *of real slavery* and *the consensual* sexual kink *of the BDSM same-named version* is...

The "on one hand/on the other hand" phrasing isn't really necessary, but if that's your preferred style then your existing usage looks fine to me.

*Though I would use "from" instead of "to" in the prior sentence ;-p*

Comment: *For*? Do you mean *from*?

Comment: ...yes, that I do.  My bad.  I must need more coffee. ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to fix this without changing the structure would be to use a semicolon, or to place the commas differently:

> 1. Drawing an equivalence between torture, false imprisonment, and rape on the one hand; and a sexual kink on the other is highly insulting.
> 2. Drawing an equivalence between torture, false imprisonment and rape on the one hand, and a sexual kink on the other is highly insulting.

Personally, I would go with the second option.

On a somewhat related note, this reminds me of the Language Log entry ["When commas are crucial to comprehension"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1311).

Comment: I think that (at least in the first sentence) you need a comma after "other".

Comment: That's a rather excellent Language Log entry. I'm fond of the Oxford comma, and am, in fact, something of an overpunctuater generally. I think I prefer your **option 1** with ShreevatsaR's emendation.